# Automated vectoring or knife tool / autotracing

Tags: knife-tool

I use the knife tool in Blender to create holes in the object geometry (trace the assigned texture). This takes a lot of time.

Is there a function or a software product to autotrace the assigned texture in 3D (like potrace for 2D)?

Thanks for help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of options depending on what you are after.

The lazy, easiest one would be to use the texture to control the transparency of your object. This would keep the poly count low, but you would not be dealing with real geometry.

[image]

Other option is to trace the shape on a program like the one you mention, or inkscape, illustrator or similar, and convert it into vector information, save it as SVG.(probably you can download the svg file directly on the same website you got that pattern from...) Import that into blender and use [**Knife Project**](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?highlight=knife%20project) or some form of boolean (you'd need to extrude the curves and convert to mesh to do that). Note that you'd have to rework your topology, as anytime you use booleans or knife project you'll end up with very ugly n-gons.

Imported SVG:

[image]

Knife Project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. My goal is to produce such art: [link](http://weburbanist.com/2010/05/22/insanely-intricate-eggshell-art-by-franc-grom/) in an universal workflow in 3D. I'm only a beginner in 3D and 3D-print. Is there a tool for autotrace in 3D? I don't know a workflow for this pattern: [link](http://img.weburbanist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/franc-grom-eggshell-art-1.jpg)

Comment: threre is no such tool in blender